# How can I reach dynamic computing of div block height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, amcharts

I'm newbie in CSS & HTML layout. And I ran into some issue.
How can I reach dynamic computing of div block height?
In my example exist two nested div blocks. Wrapper and content block who contains the legend of diagram that can be have different size. I need that if size of legend more of wrapper block, scrollbar appeared, otherwise not.
How can I reach it? Via CSS or JS and etc.
I tried write something like this, but this code binded to constant block size. If content size more than nested block, scrollbar isn't help to see hidden content. Also I have to say that I use Amcharts framework for generate charts
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPj9j.jpg Here you can see result of code( Sorry, I haven't reputation to attach the picture for a right way)

```
#chartdiv{ /*Some chart block*/
    width: 76%;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
}
#chartlegenddiv { /*Legend content block*/
    height: 280px; /* need auto computing here */
}

#chartlegendwrapper { /*Legend wrapper block*/
    width: 14%;
    height: 200px;
    float: right;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#chartdiv{ /*Some chart block*/
    width: 76%;
    height: 500px;
    float: left;
}

#chartlegendwrapper { /*Legend wrapper block*/
    width: 14%;
    max-height: 70px;
    float: right;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="chartlegendwrapper"><div>1<br>
2<br>
3<br>
4<br>
5<br>
6<br>
7<br>
8<br>
</div></div>
```

You can remove `height` from `#chartlegenddiv`.
Also replace `height` with `[max-height][1]` on `#chartlegendwrapper`.

No height is the same as `height: auto`.

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height):

> The browser will calculate and select a height for the specified element.

Comment: Is the legend content taller than its wrapper?

Comment: No, it is inside wrapper. In your example, what if content be bigger than 500px?
Also what if content be less than 70px(1 row for example). In first situation we will lost the content, in second - useless scrollbar available.

Comment: Also I have to say that I use Amcharts framework for generate charts